# JPA findByAttributeName method not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**When i am searching as findById(). It is working fine but when i am trying as findByUsername(String username) I am getting exception as**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3399) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3699) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

**The Table code for Mysql is**

```
        CREATE TABLE `user` (
            `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `REGISTER_TYPE` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
            `PROFILE_TYPE` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
            `REGISTRATION_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            `LAST_SESSION` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            `PASSWORD_EXPIRED` smallint(6) DEFAULT '-1',
            `FIELD1` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD4` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD5` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
            PRIMARY KEY(`USER_ID`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

        /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

        --
        -- Dumping data in table `user`
        --

        LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
        /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` DISABLE KEYS */;

        INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1000, 'USER', 'USER', '2019-04-16 06:19:10', '2019-04-16 06:19:10', '-1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2019-04-16 06:19:10');
        INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1001, 'USER', 'USER', '2019-04-16 06:19:10', '2019-04-16 06:19:10', '-1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2019-04-16 06:19:10');

        /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` ENABLE KEYS */;
        UNLOCK TABLES;

        --
        -- Table structure for `user_registration`
        --

        /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
        /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

        CREATE TABLE `user_registration`(
            `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
            `USERNAME` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
            `PASSWORD` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
            `PASSWORD_INVALID` smallint(6) DEFAULT '-1',
            `RESET_PASSWORD_CODE` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
            `TIMEOUT` smallint(6) DEFAULT '-1',
            `PASSWORD_CREATION_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            `RESET_PASSWORD_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            `FIELD1` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD3` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
            `FIELD4` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
            CONSTRAINT `USERNAME` UNIQUE (`USERNAME`),
            CONSTRAINT `userreg_user_key1` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

        /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

        --
        -- Dumping data in table `user_registration`
        --

        LOCK TABLES `user_registration` WRITE;
        /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user_registration` DISABLE KEYS */;

        INSERT INTO `user_registration` VALUES ('1000', 'abc@gmail.com',  'abc@123', '-1', 'RESETPASS', '-1', '2019-04-17 07:37:10', '2019-04-17 07:37:10', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2019-04-17 07:37:10');
        INSERT INTO `user_registration` VALUES ('1001', 'abcd@gmail.com','abcd@123', '-1', 'RESETPASS', '-1', '2019-04-17 07:37:10', '2019-04-17 07:37:10', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2019-04-17 07:37:10');

        /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user_registration` ENABLE KEYS */;
        UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**The Entity class for UserRegistration is**

```
 package com.model;
    // Generated Apr 26, 2019 8:02:54 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

    /**
     * UserRegistration generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_registration", catalog = "flipkart", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "USERNAME"))
    public class UserRegistration implements java.io.Serializable {

        private long userId;
        private User user;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private Short passwordInvalid;
        private String resetPasswordCode;
        private Short timeout;
        private Date passwordCreationTime;
        private Date resetPasswordTime;
        private Short field1;
        private Integer field2;
        private String field3;
        private Date field4;

        public UserRegistration() {
        }

        public UserRegistration(User user, String username, String password, Date passwordCreationTime,
                Date resetPasswordTime, Date field4) {
            this.user = user;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.passwordCreationTime = passwordCreationTime;
            this.resetPasswordTime = resetPasswordTime;
            this.field4 = field4;
        }

        public UserRegistration(User user, String username, String password, Short passwordInvalid,
                String resetPasswordCode, Short timeout, Date passwordCreationTime, Date resetPasswordTime, Short field1,
                Integer field2, String field3, Date field4) {
            this.user = user;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.passwordInvalid = passwordInvalid;
            this.resetPasswordCode = resetPasswordCode;
            this.timeout = timeout;
            this.passwordCreationTime = passwordCreationTime;
            this.resetPasswordTime = resetPasswordTime;
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
            this.field4 = field4;
        }

        @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")

        @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public long getUserId() {
            return this.userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        public User getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 128)
        public String getUsername() {
            return this.username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 128)
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Column(name = "PASSWORD_INVALID")
        public Short getPasswordInvalid() {
            return this.passwordInvalid;
        }

        public void setPasswordInvalid(Short passwordInvalid) {
            this.passwordInvalid = passwordInvalid;
        }

        @Column(name = "RESET_PASSWORD_CODE", length = 128)
        public String getResetPasswordCode() {
            return this.resetPasswordCode;
        }

        public void setResetPasswordCode(String resetPasswordCode) {
            this.resetPasswordCode = resetPasswordCode;
        }

        @Column(name = "TIMEOUT")
        public Short getTimeout() {
            return this.timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(Short timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "PASSWORD_CREATION_TIME", nullable = false, length = 26)
        public Date getPasswordCreationTime() {
            return this.passwordCreationTime;
        }

        public void setPasswordCreationTime(Date passwordCreationTime) {
            this.passwordCreationTime = passwordCreationTime;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "RESET_PASSWORD_TIME", nullable = false, length = 26)
        public Date getResetPasswordTime() {
            return this.resetPasswordTime;
        }

        public void setResetPasswordTime(Date resetPasswordTime) {
            this.resetPasswordTime = resetPasswordTime;
        }

        @Column(name = "FIELD1")
        public Short getField1() {
            return this.field1;
        }

        public void setField1(Short field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }

        @Column(name = "FIELD2")
        public Integer getField2() {
            return this.field2;
        }

        public void setField2(Integer field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        @Column(name = "FIELD3", length = 256)
        public String getField3() {
            return this.field3;
        }

        public void setField3(String field3) {
            this.field3 = field3;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "FIELD4", nullable = false, length = 26)
        public Date getField4() {
            return this.field4;
        }

        public void setField4(Date field4) {
            this.field4 = field4;
        }

    }
```

**THE SERVICE CLASS FOR UserRegistration is**

```
    package com.service;

    import java.util.Optional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.model.UserRegistration;
    import com.repository.UserRegistrationRepository;

    @Service
    public class UserRegistrationService {

        private final UserRegistrationRepository userRegistrationRepository;

        @Autowired
        public UserRegistrationService(UserRegistrationRepository userRegistrationRepository) {
            this.userRegistrationRepository= userRegistrationRepository;
        }

        /*public Optional<UserRegistration> getByUsername(String username){
            return userRegistrationRepository.retreiveByUsername(username);
            //return userRegistrationRepository.findById(username);
        }*/

        public UserRegistration getByUsername(String username){
            return userRegistrationRepository.findByUsername(username);
            //return userRegistrationRepository.findById(username);
        }
    }
```

**THE REPOSITORY FOR UserRegistration is**

```
    package com.repository;

    import java.util.Optional;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.model.UserRegistration;
    import java.lang.String;
    import java.util.List;

    @Repository
    public interface UserRegistrationRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRegistration, Long>{

        /*@Query("select u from UserRegistration u where u.username=:username")
        public UserRegistration retreiveByUsername(@Param("username")String username);*/

        /*@Query(value="select u from UserRegistration u where u.username=:username")
        public UserRegistration retreiveUsername(String username);*/

        public UserRegistration findByUsername(String username);
    }
```

**MY pom.xml is**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            4.0.0
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-starter-parent
                2.1.4.RELEASE
                 
            
            com
            JSPTest
            0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            JSPTest
            Demo project for Spring Boot

```
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <jjwt.version>0.6.0</jjwt.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR USING JSP PAGES STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY ADDED BECAUSE OF ERROR java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR USING JSP PAGES ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR JPA STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR JPA ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR MYSQL STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR MYSQL ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR SECURITY STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR SECURITY ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR JWT STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR JWT ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR org.apache.common.lang3 STARTS -->

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR org.apache.common.lang3 ENDS -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR HIBERNATE NOT REQUIRED YET STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>




            <dependency>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!--
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </dependency> -->

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR HIBERNATE NOT REQUIRED YET ENDS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DEPENDENCY FOR USING @ConfigurationProperties Annotation STARTS -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: On adding it in pom.xml it is giving me error as
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1
 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)

Comment: Seems clashes on dependencies, then remove antlr and clean and build (rebuild)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your support but i have already tried all of these things.
By removing antlr dependencies, it compiles properly but at runtime when i am hitting it. It is giving me same error as

Comment: 2019-04-30 12:52:29.397  INFO 17912 --- [nio-9097-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-04-30 12:52:29.416 ERROR 17912 --- [nio-9097-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

Comment: Can you post the link of repo so I can help you?

Comment: Thanks jonathan for your support, but it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
This resolved my issue:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

previously i was using this which was unable to create HQL queries

<dependency>
     <groupId>antlr</groupId>
     <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22891758)

Comment: What is this now?
I got the soln i posted it. Simple

Comment: You need to provide more details on how this solved your problem, which is missing here, so that if someone in future sees this question, he knows what is happening!

Comment: yup, you need to add more detail about what you did, upgrade antlr version or change something.

Comment: previously i was using this which was unable to create HQL queries

<dependency>
     <groupId>antlr</groupId>
     <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
</dependency>

I have mentioned it in my pom.xml which i have posted.
Happy now?